# polymorphic dto in a controller

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have folowed this way to use polymorphic dto in a spring controller

https://bwgjoseph.com/polymorphic-dto-using-java-record-with-jackson

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION, defaultImpl = HomeAddressDto.class)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(HomeAddressDto.class),
    @Type(OfficeAddressDto.class)
})
public interface Address {

}

public record HomeAddressDto(String street, String postalCode, String unit) implements Address {}

public record OfficeAddressDto(String building, String street, String postalCode, String unit) implements Address {}
```

That work well but in the controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/deduction/addresses")
public class DeductionAddressController {

    @PostMapping()
    public Address create(@RequestBody Address address) {
        if (address instanceof HomeAddressDto) {
            System.out.println("home");
        }

        if (address instanceof OfficeAddressDto) {
            System.out.println("office");
        }

        return address;
    }
}
```

instanceof is used, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: The url you link to presents this exact issue and the solution he used.  Have you tried that to see if it works for you?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new service with similar polymorphism, for example

```
public class DeductionAddressController {

    @Autowired
    private AddressService addressService;

    @PostMapping()
    public Address create(@RequestBody Address address) {
        addressService.processAddress(address);

        return address;
    }
}
```

where `AddressService` looks like

```
@Service
public class AddressServiceImpl implements AddressService {

   @Override
   public void processAddress(HomeAddressDto homeAddress) {
      System.out.println("home");
      // process HomeAddressDto...
   }

   @Override
   public void processAddress(OfficeAddressDto homeAddress) {
      System.out.println("office");
      // process OfficeAddressDto...
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a very good solution as well, a lot cleaner than a `Visitor` or something else of that nature.  The only problem I can see is the extra `services` that will be needed as this scales out...

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you're looking for.

Abstract (Parent) Class:

```
//I'm assuming this discriminator works
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION, defaultImpl = HomeAddressDto.class)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(HomeAddressDto.class),
    @Type(OfficeAddressDto.class)
})
public abstract class Address {
   public enum AddressType {
      HOME("home"), OFFICE("office");
      // set the rest up
   }
 
   public abstract AddressType getType();
   
}
```

Home Address Class:

```
public record HomeAddressDto(String street, String postalCode, String unit) extends Address {

   @Overrides
   public AddressType getType(){
      return AddressType.HOME;
   }
}
```

Office Address Class:

```
public record OfficeAddressDto(String building, String street, String postalCode, String unit) extends Address {

   @Overrides
   public AddressType getType(){
      return AddressType.OFFICE;
   }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/deduction/addresses")
public class DeductionAddressController {

    @PostMapping()
    public Address create(@RequestBody Address address) {
        Log.info(address.getType());
        ...
        ...
        return address;
    }
}
```